# How to start selenium server with log4j

Tags: selenium, log4j

I want to start selenium server with log4j so that all server related logs go there. I'm starting the server with ANT using the following ANT target

```xml
<target name="startserver" depends="setClassPath">
<java jar="${test.home}/lib/selenium-server-standalone-2.20.0.jar"  fork="true">
<arg line="-Djava.util.logging.config.file=log4j.properties"/>
<arg line="-firefoxProfileTemplate 'D:\selenium.default'"/>
<arg line="-browserSideLog"/>
</java>
</target>
```

My log4j.properties is as below:

```
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, R, stdout

log4j.appender.R=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.R.File=./logs/sellog.log
log4j.appender.R.MaxFileSize=10MB
log4j.appender.R.MaxBackupIndex=1
log4j.appender.R.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.R.layout.ConversionPattern=%5p [%t] (%F:%L) - %m%n

log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%5p [%t] (%F:%L) - %m%n
```

But I'm not getting any server logs after I start the server from the target.

Also, I have a selenium test where I'm throwing the log into log4j as below:

```java
private LogManager lm;
private Logger logger = lm.getLogger(this.getClass().getName());
logger.info("Selenium Client started...");
```

I'm getting application logs in log4j log.

What I want is to have all the logs (selenium server log + app log) in log4j log.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You've mixed up two logging frameworks here:

```
java.util.logging.config.file=log4j.properties
```

That constant is for configuring java.util.logging, AKA 'JDK logging'.

Are you sure that Selenium Server actually uses log4j? If it does, you should have

```
log4j.configuration=log4j.properties
```

Edit: Based on http://code.google.com/p/selenium/source/browse/trunk/java/server/src/org/openqa/selenium/server/log/LoggingManager.java, looks like it uses JDK logging, so you can't (easily) redirect it to log4j.

Answer (score 0):

Selenium uses [slf4j](http://www.slf4j.org/), which can be told to send the log data to log4j.  But you'll have to crack open the JAR manifest and specify the classpath and main class explicitly, instead of using the `-jar` option.  Then add slf4j's log4j adapter jar (slf4j-log4j12-1.6.4.jar) to the classpath, and it will all work.

Comment: Do you have a source for the claim that selenium uses slf4j? I see classes in selenium v2.32.0 that refer to `java.util.logging.Logger`s

Comment: I haven't looked at the logging code lately, but I start it like this: `java "-Dlog4j.configuration=./local.log4j.properties" -cp "./slf4j-log4j12-1.3.1.jar;./log4j-1.2.16.jar;./selenium-server.jar;." org.openqa.grid.selenium.GridLauncher -port 4464 -userExtensions "./user-extensions.js" -browserSideLog` and it works fine.